# How to create anonymous class so that it can be passed to generic constructor?

Tags: c#, generics, anonymous-types, anonymous-class

I am porting tests of a non-generic repository to a generic one. Instead of using `Repo<MyType>`, I want to test the more abstract methods with `Repo<object>` or something.

I tried to use an anonymous *instance*, but it didn't work:

```
    [Test]
    public void AddToRepoIncrementsByOne()
    {
        IFile file = new FileFake();
        IByteSerializer<object> serializer = new SerializerObjectFake();
        repo = new WriteableFileRepository<object>(file, serializer);

        var obj = new { Name = "test" };
        repo.Add(obj);

        Assert.True(repo.Items.Count() == 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(repo.Items.Single().Name, obj.Nome);
        //----------------------------------^^^^  
        //-------------------compiler error here
    }
```

I tried to infer the class reference from the object, without success too:

```
        var obj = new { Nome = "teste" };

        Type T = obj.GetType();

        IArquivo arquivo = new ArquivoFake();
        IByteSerializer<T> serializer = new SerializerObjectFake();
        //--------------^
        repo = new RepositórioArquivoEscrita<T>(arquivo, serializer);
```

How can I solve this? I am not demanding to use anonymous objects, I just thought it would be a pragmatic way to make my tests run, but I sure could do it other way if this is not a good design.

Comment: Instead of `object` as generic type, try to use `dynamic`, you should be able to access to your property `Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
IByteSerializer<object> serializer = new SerializerObjectFake();
repo = new WriteableFileRepository<object>(file, serializer);
```

Make a generic method to create your repository:

```
RepoType<T> CreateRepository<T>(IFile file, T objectForType)
{
    IByteSerializer<T> serializer = new SerializerObjectFake();
    return new WriteableFileRepository<T>(file, serializer);
}
```

Usage:

```
[Test]
public void AddToRepoIncrementsByOne()
{
    IFile file = new FileFake();
    var obj = new { Name = "test" };
    /*Your type is missing*/ repo = CreateRepository(file, obj);

    repo.Add(obj);

    Assert.True(repo.Items.Count() == 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(repo.Items.Single().Name, obj.Nome);
    //----------------------------------^^^^  
    //-------------------no more error here
}
```

By passing your anonymous object as parameter (even if you don't use it), it allows you to get its type as generic argument. Then, you can use it to instantiate the objects depending on its type.

Comment: In a test situation, this makes the fixture setup a bit more involved. I ended up creating a `TestObject` class and will use it instead of anonymous, since I think this is the correct design for my situation, but I think your answer best addresses what I have asked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The trick with anonymous types is to cast by example; let the compiler do the work for you by leveraging type inference:

```
public static T CastByExample(this object obj, T prototype) => 
    (T)obj;
```

Now all you need to do is:

```
Assert.AreEqual(repo.Items.Single().CastByExample(obj).Name, obj.Name);
```

Comment: I like this, but the only con I see, it's whenever you want to access the properties of the object, you have to cast it. Then, when you get your container, you do not know necessarely what type `object` stands for. So, for someone who get into your code, it can be a bit confusing. Nervertheless, in this case, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @romain-aga Well, one could argue that you always know a valid reference type of the item you are fetching from a repo; how would you use the fetched item otherwise?

Comment: I can't deny it, you are right in that case. Even, if you could imagine some weird implementations. It's more about in more general case, when you store anonymous types in a generic class, that you could encounter a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for fix this is via a generic method using `obj` to get the compiler to fill in the blanks:

```
var obj = new { Nome = "teste" };
Foo(obj);

...

void Foo<T>(T obj) {
    IArquivo arquivo = new ArquivoFake();
    IByteSerializer<T> serializer = new SerializerObjectFake();
    // etc
}
```

Now `T` is the anonymous type.

Comment: Anyway as soon as OP want to access the properties of that anonymous type he´s stuck as they are unknwon at compile-time. Fur serialization however this is unimportant of course.